# fsicapd command has high cpu load while idle

Tags: 22.04, cpu

The CPU load of my computer is high without me doing any major activity (even if I am not using it at all). The computer fan is running at high power to try to cool down the computer.
When I check which process is taking so much load, I see that it is a process associated to  the `fsicapd` command. I do not know what this is exactly, and I do not know what to do to solve it.

As a note, yesterday my PC CPU was high because of the `tracker-miner` command, and after some research I found out how to reduce the CPU load, by changing the settings of the tracker3 program to ignore some folders with a lot of files (following [this](http://gijskoot.nl/foss,/ubuntu/2020/02/20/ubuntu-tracker-settings.html)). This solved the issue, but now this new command (`fsicapd`) is taking most of the CPU again.

I am using Ubuntu 22.04

[image: Screenshot of the top command output]